# How do I remove the faucet handle as pictured?

Tags: plumbing, leak

I have been struggling with removing the faucet handle and I'm looking for some help.

As shown in the picture, the handle consists of 2 parts, the upper one, which controls the water flow, and the lower part. When lifted (because I have removed the nut in the cabinet), there is one pipe connecting with the lower part. I did find a set screw on the lower part and removed it successfully (note the hole on the lower part). But I'm stuck with the correct next step here, I have tried

1. rotate the lower part, it just spins indefinitely without changing position or detaching from the pipe
2. lift just the upper part, doesn't come off
3. lift both the upper and lower part, doesn't work
4. force rotating the upper part while holding the pipe, doesn't really move

I'm not really sure if the upper part will come off separately or the entire thing will detach from the pipe, so I was hesitate to apply force.

[image: Faucet Handle]

[image: Faucet Handle Lifted]

Comment: unscrew the handle

Comment: There are two holes on the base. Is there a screw of some sort there?

Comment: It is likely that the upper lever portion can be removed separately, to allow access to the stem. Often the lever itself can be unscrewed, releasing the upper lever portion. Once the upper lever portion has been removed, the lower piece can be unscrewed from the valve body after removing a set-screw that holds it. The set-screw is likely accessed with a hex wrench through that hole in the bottom of the lower piece.

Answer (score 3):

So the shorter side of the handle is actually a screw. Once removed, the upper part can then be removed easily.

Answer (score 0):

> force rotating the upper part while holding the pipe, doesn't really move

You may have to apply lubricant and attempt to move the upper part while holding the pipe. I had a much older standard faucet where the handle was immobile due to rust/water damage - the gasket was fused to the internal mechanism. Force might be necessary in this case.

Another suggestion would be to watch an installation video for that type of faucet - but I agree with Jimmy Fix-it, there is probably another hole/screw.